# Unable to change the contents of the last index of a string in C?

Tags: c, string, character

I am currently facing some issues with changing the contents of a string.

The following program I am writing rearranges words in the string src that start with a consonant such that the consonant ends up at the back (bob --> obb). Words that start with a vowel remain unchanged. The result is inserted into the string dest.

However, the last word of a sentence input always ends up with a missing consonant at the end (bob --> ob). This suggests to me that I am unable to change the contents of the last index of the string dest.

Is there a reason why?

```
void convert(char src[], char dest[]) {
    int i, isVowel, first_pos;
    int len = strlen(src);
    int count = 0;
    char first = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        while (!isspace(src[i])) {

            if (first == 0) {
                first = src[i];
                first_pos = i;
            }

            isVowel = first == 'a' || first == 'e' || first == 'i' || first == 'o' || first == 'u';

            if (isVowel == 1) {
                dest[count++] = src[i];
            }   
            else if (i != first_pos) {
                dest[count++] = src[i];
            }   

            i++;
        }   

        if (isVowel == 0) {
            dest[count++] = first;
        }   

        dest[count++] = ' ';
        first = 0;
      }
}
```

Input: "hi guys"
Expected output: "ih uysg"
Actual output: "ih uys"

Comment: Some observations: 1) `for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)` should probably be `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)` 2) `isWovel` is used uninitialized when the first character is a space

Comment: I think you have more problems than described. Try your program with input like "start" and "start here". You need to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: What output would you expect from "start here" ? Would it be "astrt eehr" or ... ?

Comment: It would be "tarts ereh"

Comment: So it is **only the first** consonant character you want to move to the end of the word, right?

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
while (!isspace(src[i])) {
```

to

```
while (src[i] && !isspace(src[i])) {
```

and the function is finally add

```
dest[count++] = '\0';
```

Modified code:

```
void convert(char src[], char dest[]) {
    int i, isVowel, first_pos;
    int len = strlen(src);
    int count = 0;
    char first = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        while (src[i] && !isspace(src[i])) {

            if (first == 0) {
                first = src[i];
                first_pos = i;
            }

            isVowel = first == 'a' || first == 'e' || first == 'i' || first == 'o' || first == 'u';

            if (isVowel == 1) {
                dest[count++] = src[i];
            }   
            else if (i != first_pos) {
                dest[count++] = src[i];
            }   

            i++;
        }   

        if (isVowel == 0) {
            dest[count++] = first;
        } 

        dest[count++] = ' ';
        first = 0;
      }
      dest[count++] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to iterate a string of words. If a word starts with a consonant you want to move that consonant to the end of the word (while keeping the rest of the word unchanged). If a word starts with a vowel you want to keep the whole word unchanged.

In your code I see a few things that look strange:

- In case the input starts with a space you use `isVowel` uninitialized which is undefined behavior
- It seems you never zero terminate the destination string

That said I think your algorithm is too complex. To get a more simple implementation consider this algorithm:

```
While unhandled characters in src:
  if current char is space 
      copy space to dest
  else
      if current char is consonant
          save current char and move to next input char
      copy rest of word to dest
      if first char was consonant
          add saved char to destination
```

The code could look like:

```
void convert(char src[], char dest[]) 
{
  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;

  while(src[i]) 
  {
    if (isspace(src[i]))
    {
      // Copy the space
      dest[count++] = src[i++];
    }
    else
    {
      int isVowel = src[i] == 'a' || src[i] == 'e' || src[i] == 'i' || src[i] == 'o' || src[i] == 'u';

      char first;
      if (!isVowel)
      {
        // Save first char and move to next char
        first = src[i];
        ++i;
      }

      // Copy rest of word
      while (src[i] && !isspace(src[i]))
      {
        dest[count++] = src[i++];
      };

      if (!isVowel)
      {
        // Add the saved char
        dest[count++] = first;
      }
    }
  }

  // Terminate destination string
  dest[count] = '\0';
}
```